# Why Apple used CLang in their OpenGL/OpenCL implementation

Tags: llvm, clang

I don't know if its the right place to ask this question. But why did Apple choose to use `llvm` and its `clang` implementation to code for OpenCL/OpenGL?? What benefits did it bring to them and how? Excuse my ignorance on this topic, I know not much about this.

Answer (score 5):

Apple created Clang as a drop in replacement to GCC for C/C++/ObjC and ObjC++. The creator of LLVM works at Apple inside their compiler divisions. In a joint effort with the University of Illinois who hosts the projects Apple has created complete replacements for GCC, GDB [see LLDB], libstdc++ [see libc++] and several new projects.

The GPLv3 was the final straw that ended Apple's interest in contributing to GCC which is the reason Apple ended it at GCC 4.2.x.

LLVM/Clang is rapidly supplanting GCC across the industry.

LLVM is now a misnomer of a title.

Present Target hardware supported in LLVM/Clang:

-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting CppBackend
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MBlaze
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
-- Clang version: 3.3

Soon added out-of-the-box AMD R600 code base.

Clang is C99 compliant. OpenCL uses a subset of C99. Clang is the most complete C11 compliant Compiler suite available free of charge.

FreeBSD has moved to LLVM/Clang as the default set up for the upcoming 10.0 distribution.

AMD and Nvidia build their OpenCL stacks with LLVM/Clang.

Intel is moving their OpenCL and much more to LLVM/Clang.

Google is all in with LLVM/Clang. Ditto for Adobe, Sony, IBM, Cray, etc.

GCC is a mess of an architecture. The modularity of LLVM/Clang makes its rate of improvement and options for developers a much greater ceiling.

The Developer and User Guides for LLVM/Clang 3.2 are now very solid, with 3.3 trunk adding a much greater amount of docs to understand the benefits of LLVM/Clang.

The pace of development of high quality compiler code is second to none.

Answer (score 2):

[Straight from an LLVM/Apple Developer](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2006-August/006492.html)

[More info, PDF Slides](http://www.llvm.org/devmtg/2007-05/10-Lattner-OpenGL.pdf)

LLVM is used in two different ways, at runtime:

1. Runtime code specialization within the fixed-function vertex-processing
   pipeline.  Basically, the OpenGL pipeline has many parameters (is fog
   enabled? do vertices have texture info? etc) which rarely change:
   executing the fully branchy code swamps the branch predictors and
   performs poorly.  To solve this, the code is precompiled to LLVM .bc
   form, from which specializations of the code are made, optimized,
   and JIT compiled as they are needed at runtime.
2. OpenGL vertex shaders are small programs written using a family of
   programming langauges with highly domain-specific features (e.g. dot
   product, texture lookup, etc).  At runtime, the OpenGL stack translates
   vertex programs into LLVM form, runs LLVM optimizer passes and then JIT
   compiles the code.

(more details in the link above)

Answer (score 0):

Because they contribute to the develop of Clang/LLVM and because source code compiled with LLVM/Clang produce faster binary than GCC ...

> Clang's developers claim that it provides reduced memory footprint and
>   increased compilation speed compared to competing compilers, such as
>   GCC. To support their claim, they present that, as of October 2007,
>   Clang compiled the Carbon libraries well over twice as fast as GCC,
>   while using about one-sixth GCC's memory and disk space.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang

Comment: that wouldn't be of any use. Why use a VIRTUAL machine to code performance critical tasks(like opengl and cl)

Comment: LLVM is not a Virtual machine ... It is a compiler for first

Comment: @Prototype Stark, what's a problem with a virtual machine? GCC is a virtual machine too (in fact, it is built of *many* virtual machines).

Comment: This is about the compilation speed, not the resulting code speed. Clang is much faster than GCC (at least for C++), and it is much more hackable (i.e., it is easier to add OpenCL support), but it is still producing a slightly slower code than GCC, not all the optimisations are tuned to a same degree of perfection yet.

Comment: @SK-logic GCC consists of many compilers. While you may argue that those compilers implement the virtual machines as which the respective input languages may be seen, this is not what most people mean by VM, and not a very useful definition in almost all contexts.

Comment: @delnan, GCC is a stack of abstract (or "virtual", which is virtually the same thing) machines (like GIMPLE, for example). The said GIMPLE is not any different from LLVM. Now, what is yours definition of "VM"?

Comment: @SK-logic Ah, I didn't think of GCC's own IRs. Yes, those are abstract machines, and I'm inclined to say that they are technically VMs too. Anyone who defines a VM primarily as a (and therefore also maintains LLVM is not a VM) will obviously beg to differ. As the latter definition is common (and useful!) I prefer the term "abstract machine" though. I maintain that it's not particular relevant for anyone but GCC developers, as those languages are internal to the compiler, and only exist for compiler passes, not as free-standing programming language.